# graph in plot_ly (R version) data frame with slider to filter which data is plotted

Tags: r, graph, 3d, slider, plotly

I have a simple dataframe (c_X, c_Y, c_Z, time) in R.

I want to first graph in plot_ly when time equals to zero.

Then I want a slider bar to go from 0 to 1 and when the slider value is at 1 filter the plot shows x,y,z scatter plot of only data with time =1 and when the slider value is at 0, filter data to only when column time=0.

```
test_x = rnorm(50)
test_y = rnorm(50)
test_z = rnorm(50)
time_0 = rep(0, 50)
df_list_1 = list('c_X' = test_x, 'c_Y' = test_y, 'c_Z' = test_z, 'time' = time_0)
df_1 = as.data.frame(df_list_1)

test_x2 = rnorm(50)
test_y2 = rnorm(50)
test_z2 = rnorm(50)
time_1 = rep(1, 50)
df_list_2 = list('c_X' = test_x2, 'c_Y' = test_y2, 'c_Z' = test_z2, 'time' = time_1)
df_2 = as.data.frame(df_list_2)

df_test = rbind(df_1, df_2)
p_all <- plot_ly(df_test, x = ~c_X, y = ~c_Y, z = ~c_Z)
p_all
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `visible` attribute for each trace to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. There is an example on Plotly's website https://plot.ly/r/sliders/#sine-wave-slider. A rough implementation of your question would be something like:

```
test_x = rnorm(50)
test_y = rnorm(50)
test_z = rnorm(50)
time_0 = rep(0, 50)
df_list_1 = list('c_X' = test_x, 'c_Y' = test_y, 'c_Z' = test_z, 'time' = time_0)
df_1 = as.data.frame(df_list_1)

test_x2 = rnorm(50)
test_y2 = rnorm(50)
test_z2 = rnorm(50)
time_1 = rep(1, 50)
df_list_2 = list('c_X' = test_x2, 'c_Y' = test_y2, 'c_Z' = test_z2, 'time' = time_1)
df_2 = as.data.frame(df_list_2)


steps <- list(
  list(args = list("visible", c(TRUE,TRUE)), 
       label = "Time 1 + 2", 
       method = "restyle", 
       value = "1 + 2"
  ),
  list(args = list("visible", c(FALSE,TRUE)), 
       label = "Time 0", 
       method = "restyle", 
       value = "1"
  ),
  list(args = list("visible", c(TRUE,FALSE)), 
       label = "Time 1", 
       method = "restyle", 
       value = "2"
  )
)

p_all <- plot_ly(type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'markers') %>%
  add_trace(x = df_1$c_X, y = df_1$c_Y, z = df_1$c_Z, name='Time 0') %>%
  add_trace(x = df_2$c_X, y = df_2$c_Y, z = df_2$c_Z, name='Time 1') %>%
  layout(title = "Visible?",
         sliders = list(
           list(
             active = 0, 
             currentvalue = list(prefix = "Time: "), 
             pad = list(t = 60), 
             steps = steps))) 
p_all
```